# Trying to separate the date time in snort log (.csv)

Tags: python, mysql, snort

I have set Snort up to output alerts into a excel.csv directly with my required information.

I am using Python to input the values in my excel.csv into a database. < This works, no issues here

However one of my values in the excel is the Snort timestamp (MONTH/DAY-HOUR:MIN:SEC.MILIIS).

I wish to separate the date and time into 2 separate columns for me to easily input it into my SQL database.

I am trying to separate the datetime (currently the format is MONTH/DAY-HOUR:MIN:SEC.MILIIS) into Date (DD/MM) and Time (HOUR:MIN:SEC).

Current format in the excel: 04/11-10:47:30.789142

What I would like:

Column 1: 04/11

Column 2: 10:47:30

Current script:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import csv
import datetime

#import my csv
#working, able to read all data
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\devon\Desktop\testSnort.csv')
print (data)



#Set column "Date Time" in the excel as the variable DateTimeList 
#Able to print out the Date+time only

DateTimeList = ["DateTime"]
datetime = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\devon\Desktop\testSnort.csv', usecols=DateTimeList)
print (datetime)
```

I am able to output the current data, and to filter out the DateTime values.

However I do not seem to be able to strip the 2 apart into different columns

Could someone advise me if it is possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that you can go about it, but if you are reading the timestamp as a string, probably the easiest way to do it is to split on the -.

```
value1, value2 = timestamp.split("-")
```

That will give you the month and day in value1 and the time in value2.

Answer (score 0):

```py
date='01/02-12:12:00.0000'
print(date.split('-'))
#['01/02', '12:12:00.0000']
```